# Nock isn't matching HTTPS call inside middleware?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nock

I have a piece of middleware that performs authentication with a third-party service via request. I do this request with superagent. Obviously I want to mock this in my tests since it slows them down quite a lot and also is dependant on the third-parties server.

When using nock, it doesn't seem to find the request at all. I even tried using the recorder and it only picks up the actual requests of my local endpoints. (Although it uses an unfamiliar IP and port?).

The request inside my middleware;

```
export default async (req, res, next) => {
      const user = await superagent
      .get(`https://example.com/session/`)
      .query({ session })
      .set('Api-Key', '1234');
}
```

My Nock Instance;

```
nock('https://example.com/session/')
  .persist()
  .get('/session/')
  .reply(200, {
    success: true,
    username: 'testuser',
  })
  .log(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues here.

First off, you define twice `/session/`:

- `nock('https://example.com/session/')`
- `.get('/session/')`

Choose:

- `nock('https://example.com').get('/session/')`
- `nock('https://example.com/session/').get('/')`

Second issue, you're adding a query string to your call (`.query({ session })`), but you don't tell that to Nock using `.query(true)`.

In the end, you should have something like:

```
nock('https://example.com/session/')
  .persist()
  .get('/') // rewrote here
  .query(true) // added here
  .reply(200, {
    success: true,
    username: 'testuser',
  })
  .log(console.log);
```